# logitech G900 Mouse autoscrolls

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, logitech, mouse-scroll

I bought a Logitech G900 mouse from which I'm very happy. On kubuntu 16.10 & 17.04 it somethimes does me like an autoscroll when the wheel is free (btn on the mouse to enable the scroll wheel with resistances or not). Am unable to understand when and why but reading pdfs or browsing the web its anoying... dont have this problem on windows